# $object->getData() returns null even though in DB there is data

Tags: php, riak

I just started using Riak (for a college project) and we got a CentOS machine with Riak 1.4.2 on it.

I made a bucket called "testbucket" and in it key,value pair "helloworld", "Hello World!" using curl. Then I tried fetching the data using curl and browser, and everything was fine, I got "Hello World!" back as intended.

The problem was that I need to make a web project using PHP and I'm stuck with the following:

```
<?php

require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/Riak.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/Bucket.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/Exception.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/Link.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/MapReduce.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/Object.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/StringIO.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/Utils.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/Link/Phase.php');
require_once('riak-php-client-master/src/Basho/Riak/MapReduce/Phase.php');

$connection = new Basho\Riak\Riak('192.168.56.12', 10018);

$bucket = new Basho\Riak\Bucket($connection, 'testbucket');
$object = $bucket->get('helloworld');
var_dump($object);

?>
```

var_dump prints the following:

```
object(Basho\Riak\Object)[3]
  protected 'meta' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'indexes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'autoIndexes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'client' => 
    object(Basho\Riak\Riak)[1]
      public 'host' => string '192.168.56.12' (length=13)
      public 'port' => int 10018
      public 'prefix' => string 'riak' (length=4)
      public 'mapred_prefix' => string 'mapred' (length=6)
      public 'indexPrefix' => string 'buckets' (length=7)
      public 'clientid' => string 'php_us1pa7' (length=10)
      public 'r' => int 2
      public 'w' => int 2
      public 'dw' => int 2
  public 'bucket' => 
    object(Basho\Riak\Bucket)[2]
      public 'client' => 
        object(Basho\Riak\Riak)[1]
          public 'host' => string '192.168.56.12' (length=13)
          public 'port' => int 10018
          public 'prefix' => string 'riak' (length=4)
          public 'mapred_prefix' => string 'mapred' (length=6)
          public 'indexPrefix' => string 'buckets' (length=7)
          public 'clientid' => string 'php_us1pa7' (length=10)
          public 'r' => int 2
          public 'w' => int 2
          public 'dw' => int 2
      public 'name' => string 'testbucket' (length=10)
      public 'r' => null
      public 'w' => null
      public 'dw' => null
  public 'key' => string 'helloworld' (length=10)
  public 'jsonize' => boolean true
  public 'headers' => 
    array (size=10)
      'http_code' => int 200
      'x-riak-vclock' => string 'a85hYGBgzGDKBVIcKlYHQkK6OW9mMCUy5bEyBGgwn+PLAgA=' (length=48)
      'vary' => string 'Accept-Encoding' (length=15)
      'server' => string 'MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.0 (never breaks eye contact)' (length=57)
      'link' => string '</riak/testbucket>; rel="up"' (length=28)
      'last-modified' => string 'Mon, 15 Dec 2014 09:39:28 GMT' (length=29)
      'etag' => string '"y0akdKQCeEWM2HBgOp0tK"' (length=23)
      'date' => string 'Mon, 15 Dec 2014 13:56:54 GMT' (length=29)
      'content-type' => string 'text/html' (length=9)
      'content-length' => string '38' (length=2)
  public 'links' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'siblings' => null
  public 'exists' => boolean true
  public 'data' => null
```

Of course, trying to do $object->getData() results in Exception.
I'm completely baffled as the data clearly exists (checked with both curl and through browser) and yet I can't seem to access it this way. It seems weird especially as the line "'content-length' => string '38' (length=2)" says that obviously there should be some data in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `get` is for json-encoded data, according to the [docs](http://basho.github.io/riak-php-client/classes/Basho.Riak.Bucket.html#method_get), try using [`getBinary`](http://basho.github.io/riak-php-client/classes/Basho.Riak.Bucket.html#method_getBinary)

Comment: Thank you! That was it! Although I thought that public 'jsonize' => boolean true meant that data was json-encoded, is that not the case?

Comment: The object you stored via curl was not valid json.  `jsonize` being true/false is exactly what differentiates get() and getBinary() - https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client/blob/develop/src/Basho/Riak/Bucket.php#L213-L236

Comment: Thank you, I understand it much better now!